# Environment when executing command using os/exec golang

Tags: go, command

I have some problems with `os/exec` module. For example, I run another project using this code:

**Noted that I created a service in Linux and ran it together with OS.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service Name

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/binary/file

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", "./cmd/build/main.go")
cmd.Dir = "/home/username/otherprojectname"
out, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

And I got an error like `exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH`. Then I added this code before running the command and

```
goPath := ":/usr/local/go/bin"
os.Setenv("PATH", os.Getenv("PATH")+goPath)
newEnv := os.Environ()

cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", "./cmd/build/main.go")
cmd.Env = newEnv
cmd.Dir = "/home/username/otherprojectname"
out, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

And I also got an error like below,

```
GOPATH set to GOROOT () has no effect
go: module cache not found: neither GOMODCACHE nor GOPATH is set
```

However, I didn't encounter any errors when I ran this code without creating a service.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: 1. Never use go run with filename arguments. 2. Precompile your stuff, don't compile it in the service. 3. Do not set GOPATH (make sure it's set nowhere, especially not for the user running the service).

Comment: In my case, I must deploy this service to manage another project, `go run filename.go` must run a file go to rebuild that project. I don't have any idea to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

To address your direct question, don't bother trying to satisfy `PATH`.

If you know the fully-qualified path to your `go` binary, specify it explicitly. I doubt that it's in `/usr/local/go/bin` — that looks to be where `go install` results are stored. It's might be located at `/usr/bin/go` but confirm by running `which go`

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/go", "run", "./cmd/build/main.go")
```

For the second error, that's Go expects to be built in a module. More information [can be found here](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) but this is the gist:

```bash
go mod init $name
go mod tidy
go build  # Or go run
```

Now for addressing your overarching goal, building binaries on the fly in an init service is... atypical.

If this is a personal or otherwise handcrafted server it's running on, build the binary once and copy to `/usr/local/bin/yourprogram`. If it's for work, build centrally and distribute the binary to each instance. Both of these are out of scope for your question here.

If you *really need* to get this going, setting up the module should get it to work. I still advise going a better route.